# How to customize rating bar size in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I used This XFControls plugin to create Rating bar in my app but This bar is too large in phones and i want to customize its size
I tried witdth request but it didn't work for me

```
xmlns:Rating="clr-namespace:AsNum.XFControls;assembly=AsNum.XFControls"
```

my xaml

```
  <Rating:RatingBar BackgroundColor="SeaGreen"

       StarCount="5" Step="0.5"  SelectedColor="Orange" HeightRequest="40"
 HorizontalOptions="Fill" UnSelectedColor="LightGray" Rate="{Binding Rating,Mode=TwoWay}">

                                        </Rating:RatingBar>
```

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this component http://laavor.com/, Install-Package RatingAndSwap -Version 1.0.0, with it you can use your own image to create its size and quantity.

Comment: Its, for free sofwatre, in another case is donation, but don't have purchase.